# Laravel 4.2 does not send email with image tags in the email body

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4

The following code is working fine:

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
    $message->to('example@gmail.com')
    ->subject('Test Subject')
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1>', 'text/html');
});

// check for failures
echo Mail::failures() ? 'Failed to send' : 'Sent';
```

However, when I added the image tag to the email's body as follows:

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
    $message->to('example@gmail.com')
    ->subject('Test Subject')
    ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1> <img src="http://absolute_path_to_image">', 'text/html'); 
});
// check for failures
echo Mail::failures() ? 'Failed to send' : 'Sent';
```

The snippet returns "Sent" without any error message. I checked the log files but found nothing. There was no information in the log file or whatsoever.

The application is under a sub-dommain with SSL key enabled such as https://secure.example.com.

Note that the app used to work on the same server but under a different subdomain like https://secure.olddomain.com. I'm not sure it is related to this.

If you have experienced this problem before, please help and share your solution.

Thanks, 
SAPNET

Comment: do you want to send attachment throw your mail?

Comment: No, I don't. Just a simple HTML email with images

Comment: This one worked for me: The image is declared in the email view like:

`<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/x/x.png') }}" alt="" />` Hope this helps you!

Comment: @SAPNET Have you checked my answer below? I have posted it after i dropped my comments here.

Comment: @Hiren Gohel: your solution also works. Thank you so much for your time. Rimon's answer is more accurate when he mentioned the absolute path of the image.

Comment: @SAPNET Ok, thanks for your reply! If it helps you, you can only upvote it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send image file in mail body you need to `embed` this like below

```
\Mail::send([], [], function ($message) {
        $message->to('example@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Test Subject')
        ->setBody('<h1>Hi, welcome user!</h1> <img src="'. $message->embed('absolute_path_to_image') .'"> ', 'text/html'); 
    });
```

[More About](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#embedding-inline-attachments)

Comment: Thanks Romon, Your solution is working. How about the email's body loaded from a file that contains images?

Comment: If you send any file throw your mail you need to attach the file inside your mail. please read the doc so you get the idea how it's work

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me: The image is declared in the email view

```
<img src="{{ $message->embed(public_path() . '/x/x.png') }}" alt="" />
```

from [Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/mail#embedding-inline-attachments) "A `$message` variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments."

Hope this helps you!